# Need to add links to a php random image script

Tags: php, image, random, hyperlink

Hi I have a script that is randomly displaying 5 images for my website, but I need to give each image a different link. I had a friend help with the code cause I'm super new to php so any help anyone could give me would be awesome! I have a load more images in my original code, but I didn't think it necessary to have them all here.

This is my code

```
<?php
    $images=array( // list of files to rotate - add as needed    
     "images/Austin-Mahone-2.jpg",
     "images/Boys-Like-Girls-1.jpg",   
     "images/Boys-Like-Girls-2.jpg",
     "images/Boys-Like-Girls-3.jpg",   
     "images/It-Boys-5.jpg" ); 
    shuffle($images);

    echo '<div class="images">';
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 5){
        echo '<img src="'.$images[$i].'" />';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Uhh, what is your question?

Comment: I need to give each image a unique link to another page

Comment: Your images array needs to be an associative array with the corresponding url

Comment: Why cant you try this?        echo '<a href="" ><img src="'.$images[$i].'" /></a>';

Comment: What pages are you trying to link to?

Comment: I tried that Jerin, but then all the links for each image will go to the same place

Comment: the link will be something like /portfolio/NameOfProject

Answer (score 0):

The associative array approach as commented.

```
<?php
$images = array(
    array("src" => "images/Austin-Mahone-2.jpg", "url" => "http://URL1"),
    array("src" => "images/Boys-Like-Girls-1.jpg", "url" => "http://URL2"),  
    array("src" => "images/Boys-Like-Girls-2.jpg", "url" => "http://URL3"),
    array("src" => "images/Boys-Like-Girls-3.jpg", "url" => "http://URL4"),  
    array("src" => "images/It-Boys-5.jpg", "url" => "http://URL15")
); 

shuffle($images);

echo '<div class="images">';

foreach ($images as $image) {

    echo '<a href="'.$image["url"].'"><img src="'.$image["src"].'" /></a>';

}

echo '</div>';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of links, and combine them with your images. Then you can just do a simple `foreach` loop to output them:

```
$links = array('link1', 'link2', 'link3'); // etc.
$combined = array_combine($links, $images);

foreach ($combined as $link => $image) {
  echo '<a href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
}
```

If each image has to have the same link each time, you could create an associative array, like so:

```
$images = array(
  'http://www.google.com' => 'Google',
  'http://www.bing.com' => 'Bing',
  'http://www.yahoo.com' => 'Yahoo'
);
```

..and just loop in the same way as above:

```
foreach ($images as $link => $image) { 
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP associative arrays:

```
<?php
$images=array(
   array(
     "image" => "images/Austin-Mahone-2.jpg",
     "link" => "http://yourlink1.com"
   ),
   array(
     "image" => "images/Boys-Like-Girls-1.jpg",
     "link" => "http://yourlink2.com"
   ),
   array(
     "image" => "images/Boys-Like-Girls-2.jpg",
     "link" => "http://yourlink3.com"
   )
 ); 

shuffle($images);

echo '<div class="images">';
$i = 0;
while($i < 5){
    echo '<a href="'.$images[$i]['link'].'"><img src="'.$images[$i]['image'].'" /></a>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

This way your array `$images` contains X associative arrays which each contains `['image']` and `['link']` values.

Read more about those arrays (and others) here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp